# ntfs: finding all files sized at 64k intervals

Tags: ntfs, file-management, file-corruption, file-search

In Windows, is there a tool or way to easily find all files (maybe within a directory tree only) to list all files whose file size is a whole multiple of 64KB?

I.e. those files that may have been truncated by a chkdsk or rounded up at one point; either way, possibly corrupt.

I liked using the fast [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) software because it takes advantage of the filesystem's built-in journal and file index of sorts, allowing me to disable the resource-intensive Windows Search service.  It doesn't have this option, aside from specifying a single exact filesize like other search software, though maybe the CLI can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use powershell for that:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { if (!($_.Length % 64kb)) { Write-Host $_.FullName } }
```

The [`get-childitem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx) cmdlet iterates over a folder (and optionally its subfolders). [Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274440/578411) the results into a [ForEach-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx) and check for the [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of the file. If it meets our criteria write the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) to the host.

Comment: Thanks. Added  `{ Write-Host  $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Length, $_.FullName }` to get a better idea of what's happening (often, similar timestamps help link effects to a single event...to group a whole class of files as "damaged/suspect").